# Slow widget update on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I have a iOS 14 widget that displays time and date but also the weather (temperature) and your daily step count. The widget works fine, but often updates (too) slow. Below the timeline we used. I can not seem to find out what’s the problem and why it is updating slow, often slower than comparable (clock) widgets.

Any idea how to make updating faster and more reliable?

```
   func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {

        let primaryTimezone = TimezoneManager.shared.primaryTimezone

        WeatherApi.shared.getCurrentWeather { weather in
            HealthManager.shared.getTodaysSteps { steps in

                var entries = [WidgetWSEntry]()
                let nextMinute = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: Date())!

                var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
                components.second = 0

                for _ in 0 ..< 30 { // refresh each minute, add 30 minutes overlap

                    let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!

                    let minute = Double(getMinute(from: entryDate, timezone: primaryTimezone))
                    let hour = Double(getHour(from: entryDate, timezone: primaryTimezone))  + Double(minute) / 60.0

                    components.minute = components.minute! + 1

                    let entry = WidgetWSEntry(
                        style: style,
                        date: entryDate,
                        timeHour: hour,
                        timeMinute: minute,
                        steps: steps,
                        weather: weather)

                    entries.append(entry)
                }
                let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMinute))
                completion(timeline)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

1. You’re asking for a new timeline every minute, which won’t work. The limits on timeline updates are undocumented, but anything more than every 15 min / a few times an hour won’t work.
2. The .after() update policy isn’t very reliable in practice. Try .atEnd instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
How could you make a clock if you can not update the timeline every minute? Do you suggest making a new timeline 4times an hour, each with 15 updates in that timeline so the clock kind of ticks per minute? Isn't this unreliable if the timeline doesn't get updated one time?

Comment: I create a timeline with 60 entries, one per minute, and then set it to expire “atEnd”. This occasionally lags a few seconds, but generally it works. You probably want to update your timelines more often for weather and step counting.

Comment: Thanks! But you can’t have more timelines per widget right? So how to separate for time and weather and steps? And what happens if your timeline expires but the restart didn’t happen, would it then need 60 more minutes or how would it get triggered again?

Comment: Correct, just one timeline per widget and reloads happen when the timeline runs out, so build a timeline  that best suits your data. If you haven’t read this I recommend it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date